# Use data in webhook to populate html form input

Tags: python, django, django-forms, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have data coming in through a webhook and I would like it to http://localhost:8000/webhooks/stripe and I would like it to fill out a form on my success.html page when redirected after the checkout.

I would like to get the customer_email to fill the email input -

```
@csrf_exempt
def stripe_webhook(request):
    payload = request.body
    sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = None

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, settings.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
        )
    except ValueError as e:
    # Invalid payload
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
    # Invalid signature
        return HttpResponse(status=400)


    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        session = event['data']['object']
        customer_email = session["customer_details"]["email"]

        document.getElementById("email").value=customer_email


    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

With the forms.py looking like this -

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget= forms.EmailInput(attrs={'id':'email'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Or do I have to use a function in the forms.py to extract the data from the webhook?

Answer (score 0):

Web hook and success page are 2 different end-points. You need to save that email somewhere (e.g. a model in DB) then fetch it when you're rendering your form.

Comment: If I saved the email in a model how would I make sure that I was able to fetch the correct email from the DB in the form?

Comment: You need to find a id/key/token and save it to DB along side of email. Something that you can also have access to in success page.